# Lemur Installation on Linux machine

Tags: linux, lemur

I am trying to install Lemur-4.12 on Linux, but when running make I get:

```
../../MakeMod:48: recipe for target 'ResultFile.o' failed
make[1]: *** [ResultFile.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/data1/myuser/lemur-4.12/retrieval/obj'
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'retrieval' failed
```

Is this a common issue? What could it be caused by, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your OS name and version.

Answer (score 0):

The lemur-4.12 code is very old. The files have time stamps 2005 and 2008.
The reliable g++ version 3.4.6 ( compat-gcc-34-c++) from Fedora / RHEL 6 / CentOS 6 can do the job. My example : OS = PCLinuxOS 2016 , compiler = `gcc34-c++-3.4.6-20.SL7.x86_64`

```
cd lemur-4.12/
export CXX=g++34 && ./configure
make
```

Install result : bin/{ 29 executable´s } , lib/liblemur.a , include//[headers].hpp

---

Note : The Fedora g++34/gcc34 packages have been rebuilt, and are available for CentOS 7, Debian, Ubuntu.